# Perl array as an object variable

Tags: java, arrays, perl, variables, object

If I had a Java class as below, what is the similar Perl representation for the same?

```
class Temp {
  int my_int;
  int my_array[];

  Temp() {
  }
};
```

Specifically, I am interested to know how to use array as an object variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
package Temp;

sub new {
    my $self = bless {
        'my_int' => 0,
        'my_array' => [] # The trick here is to use an array *reference*
                         # hence the square brackets rather than ()
    };
    return $self;
}
```

For the (much!) longer answer, have a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html), and [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) for an introduction to references, lists of lists, and a OOP bootcamp, respectively. Once you've got your head around the basics, consider using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) for a more advanced approach to OOP in Perl.

Comment: Good call - added that to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose), the class could be written as:

```
package Temp;

use Moose;

has 'my_int' => (
    'is'  => 'rw',
    'isa' => 'Int',
);

has 'my_array' => (
    'is'  => 'rw',
    'isa' => 'ArrayRef[Int]',
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable();
```